# Adding clustered index on temp table to improve performance

Tags: sql-server

I have ran an execution plan and noticed that the query is taking time while inserting into temp tables. We have multiple queries that insert into temp tables. I have shared two of them below. How do I add the clustered index to the temp table via the storedprocedure query. It needs to create the index on the fly and destroy it

```
    if object_id('tempdb..#MarketTbl') is not null drop table #MarketTbl  else

        select 
            mc.companyId,
            mc.pricingDate,
            mc.tev,
            mc.sharesOutstanding,
            mc.marketCap 
        into #MarketTbl
        from ciqMarketCap mc
        where mc.pricingDate > @date
        and mc.companyId in (select val from @companyId)
        ---- pricing table: holds pricing data for the stock pprice

if object_id('tempdb..#PricingTbl') is not null drop table #PricingTbl else
        select
            s.companyId,
            peq.pricingDate,
            ti.currencyId, 
            peq.priceMid
        into #PricingTbl
        from ciqsecurity s
            join ciqtradingitem ti on s.securityid = ti.securityid
            join ciqpriceequity peq on peq.tradingitemid = ti.tradingitemid
        where s.primaryFlag = 1
            and s.companyId in (select val from @companyId)
            and peq.pricingDate> @date
            and ti.primaryflag = 1
```

**Execution plan**
[image]

Comment: Did you try CREATE INDEX?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clustered index on temp table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663967/clustered-index-on-temp-table)

Comment: Are you trying to improve INSERTs into the temp tables or SELECTs against the temp tables?

Comment: I am trying to improve the inserts as the stats are showing inserts are expensive

Comment: I have amended the storedprocedure query to like this if object_id('tempdb..#MarketTbl') is not null drop table #MarketTbl  else
 CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX index1 ON #MarketTbl(companyId)

Comment: I am getting an error Cannot find the object "#MarketTbl" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.

Comment: do i need to mention the path of the temp table while creating an index or  is it because i dont have permissions on temp table.

Comment: You can't really speed up inserts because they are IO bound. If anything, adding an index might marginally slow down inserts because of the overhead of maintaining the B-Tree. Have you considered table variables as an alternative to temp tables? They are usually memory resident unless you max out your memory.

Comment: @robertdeniro table variables are not "memory resident unless you..." and you can find them in tempdb sys.tables as well as temp tables

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is pure nonsense. You have to speed up your select, not insert.
And to speed it up you (maybe) need indexes on tables from which you select.

What you are doing now is trying to add a clustered index to a table that does not exist (the error tells you about it!), and the table does not exist because if it exists you drop it

Comment: I have updated the post with the execution plan. It shows more for the insert. What improvement are you suggesting for the select. can you give me an example

Comment: Even "if it shows more for insert", it doesn't mean you should insert into clustered index. Adding index to destination will only add SORT to your plan, sort is not gratis

Comment: For example in the first query pricingDate is indexed. Not sure what improvement can i perform on the select

Answer (score 0):

1.First, your data is not more than 5 to 10 thousand, do not use temp table, use table type variable.
2.You can create the index, after inserting the data, use alter table syntax.

Comment: I tried creating a table variable and declared the first field as primary key in the table declaration . This table is referenced further down the line in the query. It's taking more time compared to temp table approach. Nearly a minute more